# Property Grid Color Picker control not allowing custom color editing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, color-picker

When using the Property Grid and exposing a color property from an object you get this kind of interface for color selection:

[Property Grid Color Picker Image http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/692deeb28e2cc0102294908f3a02f1574g.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/692deeb28e2cc0102294908f3a02f1574g.jpg)

There are tabs for System and Web, those are fine, but the Custom tab (shown) which seems to be a subset of the standard windows color picker, seems to be hobbled. How do you create custom colors? How do you get custom colors into those white color boxes provided? Is there a setting or attribute i'm missing or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click one of those white boxes at the bottom and the `Define Color` dialog will pop up where you can create an extra colour.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Never thought to try that!